# Display students of class XII

Tags: python, dataframe

```
 RollNo       Name Class         DOB Gender    City  Marks
0       1      Naman   XII  1995-05-09      M   Anand    453
1       2    Nandini     X  1997-04-08      F  Baroda    551
2       3  Nakshatra     X  1997-03-02      F  Baroda    553
3       4   Shailesh    XI  1995-04-07      M   Surat    458
```

how to get the ouptut to dispay name and the class who are XII

Answer (score 0):

To filter pandas dataframe, use these:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(...)
df = df[ df["Class"] == "XII" ]
```

These should output:

```
 RollNo       Name Class         DOB Gender    City  Marks
0       1      Naman   XII  1995-05-09      M   Anand    453
```

To display the name only:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(...)
df = df[ df["Class"] == "XII" ]
print(df["Name"])
```

It should outputs:

```
  Name 
0 Naman
```